# Axis labels are cut off when saving MATLAB figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Consider the following MWE with produces a figure:

```matlab
clear 
close all

fig1 = figure(1);
set(gca,'xscale','log')
set(gca,'yscale','log')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Amplitude (dB)')
set(gca,'FontUnits','points',...
'FontWeight','normal',...
'FontSize',10,...
'FontName','Times',...
 'Units','normalized');

PaperW = 16;
PaperH = 7.5;
fig1.Units = 'centimeters';
fig1.Position = [20 10 PaperW PaperH];
fig1.PaperUnits = 'centimeters';
fig1.PaperPosition = [0 0 PaperW PaperH];

print(fig1,'fig1.png','-dpng','-r300')
```

I'm trying to save this as a `.png` file using `print`. Additionally, I want the saved image to be 16cm by 7.5cm. I specified this using `PaperW` and `PaperH` (the width and height).

The problem is, the bottom of the `xlabel` text is cut off. Why is this happening? And how can I solve this problem?

[image]

Zoomed in on the `xlabel`. Notice how the bottom of the `q` and `y` are cut off.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tinker around the position of the axis as follows,

```
% get axis position, move up the y co-ordinate by just little bit and offset the height by the same amount
pos = get(gca, 'Position');
set(gca, 'Position', [pos(1) pos(2)+0.05 pos(3) pos(4)-0.05]);
```